# C# WPF Gridview will not show data Unless clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am learning WPF/C# and trying to develop a small application that lists the file names in a datagrid (Windows 10, .Net frame 4.5)
So far the code is below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ProcessFiles.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ProcessFiles : Window
    {
        List<FileInfo> myFileList = new List<FileInfo>();


        public ProcessFiles()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dGrid.UpdateLayout();
        }

        private void pButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ListMyFiles(myFileList));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error " +ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Done.");
            }

            dGrid.ItemsSource = myFileList;
        }

        private void ListMyFiles(List<FileInfo> mylist)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();

            foreach (FileInfo f in new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Dummy2").GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
            {
                // var currentFile = f;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    this.ReadyItem.Content = "Updating..." + f.FullName;
                    mylist.Add(f);
                }), DispatcherPriority.Background);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I am facing a dilemma with automatically refreshing the datagrid once after the Dispatcher task completes. If I don't activate the GUI thread with a MessageBox.Show() somewhere in the button clicked event, the GridView doesn't show any data, however, maximizing the main window, adding a MessageBox show etc start displaying the columns filled.

What I must be missing?

Comment: Are you implementing INotifyPropertyChanged to let the UI know that the ItemSource of your gridview has changed?

Comment: As I mentioned, I am a true beginner with C# and WPF, I have examined many threads over here explaining INotifyPropertyChanged , beyond my understanding at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the `List<T>` to `ObservableCollection<T>` to inform the `ItemsSource` about changes. WPF Controls generally listen to `INotifyPropertyChanged` or `INotifyCollectionChanged` events:

`ObservableCollection<FileInfo> myFileList = new ObservableCollection<FileInfo>();`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public partial class ProcessFiles : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public void SetPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private ObservableCollection<FileInfo> myFileList = new ObservableCollection<FileInfo>();

    public ObservableCollection<FileInfo> MyFileList
    {
         get{return myFileList;}
         set
            {
               myFileList = value;
               SetPropertyChanged("MyFileList");
            }
    }

    public ProcessFiles()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dGrid.UpdateLayout();
    }

    private void pButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ListMyFiles(myFileList));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " +ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Done.");
        }

        dGrid.ItemsSource = MyFileList;
    }

    private void ListMyFiles(ObservableCollection<FileInfo> mylist)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();

        foreach (FileInfo f in new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Dummy2").GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
        {
            // var currentFile = f;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                this.ReadyItem.Content = "Updating..." + f.FullName;
                mylist.Add(f);
            }), DispatcherPriority.Background);
        }

    }
```

This should work

Comment: I'm getting an error at this statement "PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
"

Comment: Which error? That is the implementation of the event that notify the UI the changes

Comment: @RajeshThampi i made a fix in my answer. I did a mistake on the ListMyFiles method. Try now

Comment: However i am afraid that you can't simply update your UI in this way. Maybe you should consider the possibility to use a background worker with the Progress Changed event

Comment: I am getting the error as seen with the image (https://ibb.co/jANvQ6). I have another example with background worker and was trying to learn the major differences between Dispatcher invoke and background workers. Thanks

Comment: It looks like an error associated with C# version. I am using VS 2013 Pro edition. I am using .Net Framework 4.5 (hence C# should be Version 5) which is not supporting the short code for property change.

Comment: Changed the propertychanged?.Invoke with the following,   public void SetPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            // PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        } & it worked.

Comment: glad that it worked and i didn't got the accepted answer :D

Comment: The answered solution was the easiest considering my limited exposure to C#. Next time :) thanks once again.